# Global Cordova 7.1.0 fails to build for iOS remote device

Tags: visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-cordova

**To reproduce my issue follow these steps:**

- Visual Studio 2017 Community - version 15.4.4
- Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova - version 15.120.6728.2
- Create a Blank App (Apache Cordova)
- Changed config.xml -> Cordova Toolset -> Global Cordova 7.1.0
- Install all the required software on MAC
- Configure Remote Agent Configuration in VS Options
- Start Debugging - Debug mode - iOS platform - Remote Device

**This is the result:**

> Sending the build to the remote build server
>
> Incremental Build: False
>
> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.FileMirroring.targets(256,5): error MSB4018: The "VsTac" task failed unexpectedly.
>
> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.FileMirroring.targets(256,5): error MSB4018: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'C:\Users\uadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\appAsTgz.tgz'.
>
> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.FileMirroring.targets(256,5): error MSB4018: File name: 'C:\Users\uadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\appAsTgz.tgz'
>
> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.FileMirroring.targets(256,5): error MSB4018:    at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
>
> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.FileMirroring.targets(256,5): error MSB4018:    at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
>
> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.FileMirroring.targets(256,5): error MSB4018:    at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
>
> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.FileMirroring.targets(256,5): error MSB4018:    at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode)
>
> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.FileMirroring.targets(256,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.MultiDeviceHybridApps.MdaBuildTasks.RemoteBuild.AppAsTgzStream(String changeTimeFile, JObject lastChangeTimesMap)
>
> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.FileMirroring.targets(256,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.MultiDeviceHybridApps.MdaBuildTasks.RemoteBuild.Build()
>
> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.FileMirroring.targets(256,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.MultiDeviceHybridApps.MdaBuildTasks.VsTac.BuildPlatform()
>
> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.FileMirroring.targets(256,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.MultiDeviceHybridApps.MdaBuildTasks.VsTac.Execute()
>
> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.FileMirroring.targets(256,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
>
> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.FileMirroring.targets(256,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.d__26.MoveNext()
>
> 1>Done building project "BlankCordovaApp1.jsproj" -- FAILED.
>
> ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
>
> ========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========

Can anyone from the Cordova development team look into this issue please?

This is a screenshot of the full Build output:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/oyPW1.jpg

Comment: It works fine for me using cordova 7.1.0 on a OS X Sierra environment with the latest xcode, and cordova-ios 4.5.3. This really a local problem with your pc, maybe software blocking the files? Since this is complaining on your windows environment. Have you tried deleting all the generated files?

Comment: @Sander yes I did try that.

Comment: Do you have AV software or something running? MSB4018 has to do with link failure aka file access that's not working. It even says it cant find the file to upload to the mac. (the TGZ file)

Comment: @Sander I have Avira and I've also tried with the antivirus disabled. Unfortunately, same result. Did you actually followed the same steps I described above? Apparently I'm not the only one.. see this page's comments: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/cross-platform/tools-for-cordova/first-steps/installation

Comment: Yes I have created a blank app, which builds fine. Just like my current Ionic app that I am developing at this moment. Maybe it's somewhere in the node/npm versions? I've had issues because of those before.

Answer (score 4):

Downgrade from node 8.x+ to node 6.x and try again.