# Difficulties with Cordova-IOS remotebuild in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-cordova, cordova-ios

I’m having trouble running a remote build on Cordova IOS using Visual Studio 2017.

## Issue Background

Initially, when attempting to build remotely I was hitting the following error:

> Build failed with error Remotebuild requires your projects to use
>   cordova-ios 4.3.0 or greater with XCode 8.3

At the time, my config.xml looked like so:

[Config.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aD6A7.jpg)

It doesn’t look like updating to the latest patch actually does anything (stuck on 4.4.2), so in the end after much digging I followed the advice found here:  [VsTac task failed, could not find file appAsTgz.tgz when using global Cordova toolset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47524425/vstac-task-failed-could-not-find-file-appastgz-tgz-when-using-global-cordova-to)

I followed the steps both Mac and Windows.  The only difference is I’m using `remotebuild –secure false` rather than setting up mac permissions.
In Visual Studio, my config.xml now looks like this:

[Current config.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n40mS.jpg)

## Current Issue

When I now attempt a remote build, I get the following error:

> Remote build error from the build server  - Build
>   failed with error Cannot read property 'fail' of undefined

Unfortunately, this error is very vague and I can’t find anything on it.

The output on Terminal is:

```
WebDev-MacBook-Pro:~ XXXX$ remotebuild --secure false
Remote build server listening on [http] port XXXX
Please view/edit server configuration at /Users/XXXX/.taco_home/RemoteBuild.config. You many need to run 'remotebuild saveconfig' to generate it. You will have to restart the server if you update the server configurations.
New build request submitted:
/build/tasks?command=build&vcordova=8.0.0&cfg=debug&options=--device
{"content-type":"multipart/form-data;","host":"XXXX","content-length":"11632595","expect":"100-continue","connection":"Keep-Alive"}

Downloading: taco-remote-multiplexer
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/XXXX/.taco_home/node_modules/taco-remote-multiplexer/latest/package.json'
npm WARN latest No description
npm WARN latest No repository field.
npm WARN latest No README data
npm WARN latest No license field.

taco-remote-multiplexer downloaded and installed.
Error: Cannot find module '/Users/XXXX/.taco_home/node_modules/taco-remote-multiplexer/latest/node_modules/taco-remote-multiplexer'
Build will be executed under: /Users/XXXX/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/698
Saving build request payload to : /Users/XXXX/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/698
Saved uploaded build to /Users/XXXX/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/698/upload_698.tgz
POST /cordova/build/tasks?command=build&vcordova=8.0.0&cfg=debug&options=--device 202 1595.955 ms - 637
GET /cordova/build/tasks/698 200 2.805 ms - 637
Extracted app contents from uploaded build request to /Users/XXXX/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/698/cordovaApp. Requesting build.
Taking 698 as current build
Done with current build. Checking for next build in queue.
GET /cordova/build/tasks/698 200 6.100 ms - 787
GET /cordova/build/tasks/698/log 200 2.268 ms -
```

I should point out that I could see the error mentioned in the terminal output window regarding the remote-multiplexer in my previous build attempt as outlined in the issue background.

Has anyone encountered this or similar?  From here, how can I perform a successful remote build on cordova 4.3?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I have found similar question on Microsoft git repo:

[Problems installing taco-remote-multiplexer](https://github.com/Microsoft/remotebuild/issues/8)

Try step below:

> I'm not sure what the specific error you're hitting is, but I would
>   suggest going to your mac running remotebuild, shut down remotebuild,
>   `run rm -r ~/.taco_home/node_modules`, then start up remotebuild again.
>   That will clear out all the caches we have, and hopefully get things
>   working again. If that fails, we'll have to investigate further.