# How do I fix VsTac task failed unexpectedly

Tags: ios, visual-studio, visual-studio-cordova

I am trying to test my app on an IOS device and if I try using local Device or Remote Device, I get one error which is "The "VsTac" task failed unexpectedly" error code is MSB4018.

I am using Cordova 6.3.1 and node.js version 10.15.3, I have followed all the instructions on how to set up remotebuild on mac but this error is stopping me.

Answer (score 0):

As per the answer here you need to downgrade to node.js 6.x. Hopefully someone can come up with a better solution some time soon because node.js 6.x has reached end of life.

[VsTac task failed, could not find file appAsTgz.tgz when using global Cordova toolset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47524425/vstac-task-failed-could-not-find-file-appastgz-tgz-when-using-global-cordova-to)